# LINQ not returning the right ROW of data

Tags: c#, linq

This is my full set of data, and the highlighted row should be returned by my query but its not returning any data.

http://screencast.com/t/S0DgVgIuQS

and the linq is like this

```
if (filtro.Equals("Pendientes"))
{
     var activididadesFiltradas = actividades
               .Where(p => (Convert.ToDateTime(p.fechaVencimiento) >= DateTime.Today) 
                   && (Convert.ToDateTime(p.fechaVencimiento) <= DateTime.Today.AddDays(7)) 
                   && (p.estado != "Documentada")).ToList();
     return activididadesFiltradas;
}
```

basically it should return data where fechavencimiento is between today and 7 days in the future, and estado different to Documentada, if you see the screenshot, the conditions are met.

btw, the dataset has the dates in string, so I have to convert them before comparing

Upodate1

I also tried this but no results

```
var present = DateTime.Today;
                    var future = DateTime.Today.AddDays(7);
                    var validIDs = actividades
                            .Select(s => new
                            {
                                id = s.ID,
                                filter = s.fechaVencimiento,
                                date = Convert.ToDateTime(s.fechaVencimiento, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ),
                                present = new DateTime(present.Year, present.Month, present.Day),
                                future = new DateTime(future.Year, future.Month, future.Day)
                            })
                            .Where(m => (m.date - m.present).TotalDays >= 0 && (m.future - m.date).TotalDays >= 0 && !m.filter.Equals("Documentada"))
                            .Select(s => s.id);

                    var activididadesFiltradas = actividades.Where(a => validIDs.Contains(a.ID)).ToList();
```

Update 2

This is the record that should be returned:

http://screencast.com/t/1SUjRV2rVGa

Comment: Have you checked that your dates are parsing correctly? Culture etc?

Comment: Relying on Convert.ToDateTime without specifying a culture is kind of dangerous.

Comment: I would say the same thing that sign said, the problem is probably the convertion, not the query.

Comment: What data type is `p.fechaVencimiento` and why are you converting it to a date. Is it not a date already, and if are you storing date strings in the database? If you are don't this is likely the cause of your problems.

Comment: I'd recommend against using `DateTime` when it comes to timestamp information which may be time-zone sensitive; instead use `DateTimeOffset` to mark specific points in time. Read more on [this MSDN page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/03/31/the-death-of-datetime.aspx).

Comment: its a string on the dataset, not datetime

Comment: @EstebanV That is the route cause of your problem, don't use strings for this.

Comment: @EstebanV: Yes, a string which you are parsing to a `DateTime`. What format is this string in? Does it contain time zone information?

Comment: please see my update and screenshot, thats the record that should be returned, I guess problem is the format  right?  How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparisons don't take the time component into account.  Even if your date is parsed correctly, if it doesn't contain a time element in the string representation, you might end up in a situation where your date is 2015/01/01 00:00:00:000 and 'today' is 2015/01/01 03:12:56:001.  Seeing that you're only interested in days, I would suggest 'normalising' your dates first and then filtering based on the result.

Possibly something like this:

```
    var format = "dd/MM/yyyy";

    var present = DateTime.ParseExact (DateTime.Today.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    var future = DateTime.ParseExact (DateTime.Today.AddDays (7).ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var activididadesFiltradas = actividades
        .Where(p => ((DateTime.ParseExact(p.fechaVencimiento, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) - present).TotalDays >= 0)
            && (future - DateTime.ParseExact(p.fechaVencimiento, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).TotalDays >= 0
            && (p.estado != "Documentada")).ToList();

    return activididadesFiltradas;
```

Comment: the fields themselves never use a time, the info comes from a sharepoint list, so we always set the time behind the scenes to midnight

Comment: what about Culture? isnt thaproblem?t

Comment: the query still doesnt return anything

Comment: please see my update and screenshot, thats the record that should be returned, I guess problem is the format  right?  How can I fix that?

Comment: What's the format of your dates - can you post an example?

Comment: Example updated with date format explicitly specified.

Answer (score 2):

```
`"(Convert.ToDateTime(p.fechaVencimiento) >= DateTime.Today)"`
```

`7/09/2015` is definitely not `>=` today (in `MM/dd/yyyy`) format

Comment: In Spain, it is. That's why the most likely reason for the problem is not having used the right culture (his computer might think like you).

Comment: That depends on the parsing of `7/09`.  If the intended value is 7 September, then yes that is greater than today (where "today" is 3 September).  Hence the comment by @varocarbas to use a locale in the date conversion.

Comment: @varocarbas: Huh, your comment on this answer wasn't there when I started typing.  I got ninja'd.

Comment: @CodeswithHammer Some times I do magic :) No, I wrote it a while ago, you missed it.

Comment: guys, this is more a comment than an answer, please tell me how to correct it.

Comment: @EstebanV Use the overload of Convert.ToDateTime which accepts a Culture as argument and use the same one that the one in your computer. Or Better: apply the same culture (invariant, for example) to all the dates including DateTime.Today.

Comment: Or maybe store dates as dates so you can compare them with other dates without parsing out strings.

Comment: please see my update and screenshot, thats the record that should be returned, I guess problem is the format  right?  How can I fix that?